# Написание скрипта на Python 3 под Linux

Tags: python-3.6

Хочу написать скрипт на Python 3, который будет копировать директорию при запуске и при каждом новом запуске к названию директории будет добавляться текущая дата и версия в виде простого числа. Например NameDir_23.02, NameDir_23.02_1, NameDir_23.02_2, ... . С копированием всё понятно. Есть вопрос: как реализовать счётчик запусков скрипта внутри него самого и доступ к текущему системному времени? Возможно ли такое в принципе сделать в виде скрипта?

Comment: либо пытайся делать сам, и если что-то не получится пиши сюда с кодом, либо иди на фриланс, за тебя работу делать никто не будет

Comment: Никак. Счетчик нужно сохранять вне скрипта.

Comment: @Эникейщик, тебе его сама файловая система хранит.

Comment: @Qwertiy не понял, что именно она хранит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- версию кладешь в файл,
- дату используешь текущую,
- при перезапуске скрипта читаешь версию из файла, берешь текущую дату, конкатенируешь их -

````
   file_version+=1
   f'{file_name}_{file_date}_{file_version}'```

 - записываешь file_version в старый файл
 - done
````

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Сделал проще, добавил к имени директории текущую дату и время. Работает.

Comment: Всё равно получится криво, если запустить одновременно.